# How can i have many radio buttons on an image? (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css

I want to have 8 radio buttons in one image. To be more specific i want to have an image of hawaai islands. Different radio button every island so i can choose one. Thank you very much

Comment: You want the radio buttons to be over the image ?

Comment: yes i want them over the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use absolute position then.

```css
div {
  height:400px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #124578;
  position: relative;
}

#radio01 {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:50%;
}

#radio02 {
  position:absolute;
  left:calc(100% - 25px);
  top:25%;
}

#radio03 {
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:70%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form action="">
    <input type="radio" id="radio01" name="radio" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio02" name="radio" />
    <input type="radio" id="radio03" name="radio" />
  </form>
</div>
```